# Recursion analysis using Master Theorem

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation, recursion

I have the following algorithm:

```
MyFunction(A, i, j):
if (i + 1) >= j:
return
k = [(j - i + 1)/4] # round up
MyFunction(A, i, i + k)
MyFunction(A, i + k, i + 2 * k)
MyFunction(A, i + 2 * k, i + 3 * k)
MyFunction(A, i + 3 * k, j)
for a from i to j:
m = i
for b from i to j:
if A[b] > A[m]:
m = b
swap A[m] with A[a]
```

My goal is to express the running time of the algorithm T(n) as a recurrence relation.
and find the asymptotic complexity of T(n) using Master Theorem. Basically, I don't understand, how to convert recursion from code to formulas. With simple cases of recursion, (like Fibonacci, etc.) it's obvious, but how to make it with anything harder?

Comment: you have to properly indent your code so it is clear how it functions

Comment: effectively the recursion breaks the interval i, j in 4 subintervals of length k each

Comment: you can take n=j-i

Comment: @NikosM., here $k$ is approximately $(j - i) / 4$, i.e., 4 subproblems of size 1/4.